# How can I pick keys of an interface by their value types?

Tags: typescript

Assuming this code:

```
const add = <T, S>(prop: keyof T, item: S) =>
  setEntity({
    ...input,
    [prop]: [...(input[prop] || []), item]
  })
```

Instead of `keyof T`, which accepts any key of `T`, the type of `prop` should pick only the properties of `T` whose values are assignable to `S[]`.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
type S = string | number;

interface T {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
  baz: number;
  something: object;
}

type Assignable<Obj, Item> = {
  [Key in keyof Obj]: Obj[Key] extends Item ? Key : never
}[keyof Obj];

type Example = Assignable<T, S>; // "foo" | "baz"
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAylC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcBbAIwlQG4BYAKHq2EoDMBDAY2gBUoBvelCgsA9iIBcyNFmy06Qsm1SSyYgDYQ2mOQrYAvScXKUdyESQjAAFjMkiyAKwgdgcgL716oSFACCSJHRsTDYyDQAeAHlHABooAElmEgA+BH5BKABtAGkIECgsKABrPJEWKGiHAF1JSpy8qqgIAA9mTAATJASkqAB+KFz8wwgAN0p6N0ySkDKKxyq5L3BoAFFmthIwDTT-QODQiO44mGSqKAB6c6gAIlERa-wbxT1r+iA)